# Ionic (v3.19.1): Created file is not visible using ionic-native/file

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I create a file with the plugin ionic-native/file. ([docs/native/file/](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/))

The source code looks like this:

```
let path = this.file.externalRootDirectory + "Download";        

this.file.createFile(path, "test.txt", true).then(event => {
    this.file.writeExistingFile(path, "test.txt", "Hello 
        World!").then(event => {
           console.log('success');
        }).catch(event => {});
    console.log('success');
}).catch(event => {});
```

Everything works to this point. The file is created and then filled with content. The problem is that the file is not visible in the Downloads folder. After the installation of an additional App (FXexplorer) you can see that the file exists.

View of the **Download folder with FXexplorer**:

[image]

View of the **Download folder with the Android Download Manager**:

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link below it will may help you  https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/